# Render partial with locals inside a form_for tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this form (simplified)

```
<%= form_for @client do |client| %>
 <%= render "some_partial", foo: 10, bar: 20 %>
<% end %>
```

I also try with: `<%= render :partial => "some_partial", :locals => {foo: 10, bar: 20} %>`

And in `some_partial`:

```
<%= foo %>
<%= bar %>
```

But, the variables are not available on partial:

```
undefined local variable or method `foo' for #<#<Class:0x007fb35027bbd0>:0x007fb350536e60>
```

If I put `render` out side of `form_tag` works fine

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE1**: At the end of form, I have this:

`<%= link_to_add_association 'Add', client, :client_addresses, class: "ui mini green button add_client_address" %>`

If I remove this part, works fine...

Comment: You are using Cocoon gem correct? Can you post the complete Form code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention parameters as locals, like this.

```
<%= render :partial => "some_partial", :locals => {foo: 10, bar: 20} %>
```

Comment: Hi,
Well, I already tried that too. Sorry for not mentioning. I will update the question.

Comment: For strange reason, I only works if I remove this: ``                <%= link_to_add_association 'Add', client, :client_addresses %>``

Answer (score 0):

Is the `"some_partial"` the same `:client_addresses` you are trying to load with the `link_to_add_association`?

I believe that the error message you are experiencing is coming from within the `link_to_add_association`

Seems you are using the [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).  In order to pass locals into the partial that Cocoon uses (`:client_addresses` in your case) you need to pass the parameter `render_options: { locals: {foo: bar}` for the `link_to_add_association`

Comment: Both partials are ``client_addresses``. Right about ``render_options``. But I need pass locals when render the view, not when click on ``link_to_add_association``.

Comment: Cocoon will ```render``` the partial on page load.  Not when you click on the ```link_to_add_association```  If the ```locals``` are not present within the ```link_to_add_association``` declaration it will cause the error that you are seeing.

Since you are loading the same ```client_addresses``` partial that has
```<%= foo %>``` ```<%= bar %>```

These locals are expected to be passed in.  [Here] (https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#render_options) is the documentation from Cocoon.